# Retrieve datarow (editurl case)in jqgrid dynamic colmodels or paramter name

Tags: jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

Good Morning,
How can I retrieve data row at the asp.net controller action, in the case of editing a row in which my col model is generated dynamically, it means that I can't know the col models header only on post execute.

Comment: You should post more implementation details. How you create jqGrid, for example? How looks the controller methods (declaration of the interface at least). It's the forum for developer. You should formulate the question so that it could have some value for other people and not only for you. If you write about editing of the row, you should write which editing mode you use (inline editing or form editing) and how you do this (formatter: "actions", `inlineNav` or direct call of `editRow` or `editGridRow`). You should write which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid.

Comment: If you write about generating `colModel` dynamically you should specify more details too. You question means that you set `editable: true` *not in all* columns. Which other columns you want to send to the server? All or someone? Typically if you hold the data in the database then the `rowid` which you use to fill the grid provides you already all required information and so no other information is required: only the rowid and the new/modified data from the row. Your question could mean for example that you set no rowid or to choose not the best rowid. In any way more details are required.

Comment: I generate the col model using a list dictionnary (some col model name are dynamic: concatenation of words and numbers example : week2, week3,..)
the editing mode is inline edit, and I'd like to send some columns

Comment: All what you wrote can be implemented without the problem, which you posted. I repeat that you should post **more implementation details** (typically the code or code fragments, which shows what you do). I asked you many question which you don't answered. Thus I can only guess. You can try to add `editable: "hidden"` to the columns, which are non-editable, but which you want to send to the server on editing. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for details.

Comment: the issue is that i don't know the name of the colums within i retrieve the data.
In the header of the action controller :
<!-- language: c# -->
public string editLine(int id,string name, string week1,string week2...

the variable name is not static, it maybe week1, week2, week50..so in this cas I cannot specifiy the name of each variable int the controller methode.

Comment: **You can click on "edit" link below the question and to append it with the code or any other additional information.** ASP.NET have many possibilities to get all parameters, which posted to the server (to controller action). Alternatively you can use `serializeSaveData` callback of inline editing or `serializeRowData` callback of jqGrid to send the data *in any other form*. For example you can send all information in *one* array of objects with `name` and `value` properties. Such object can be easy read on the server side.